# Selecting multiple rows of data from a subtable along with the parent row table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have two tables in my database roughly laid out as below

Client

```
id |  other data
1  |  data 1
2  |  data 2
3  |  data 3
4  |  data 4
```

Employee assigned

```
id  | clientid | employee
1   | 1        | Fred
2   | 1        | Jim
3   | 3        | Peter
4   | 4        | Fred
5   | 4        | Peter
6   | 4        | James
```

Is there a way to return the client table with all of the employee records from the employee table?  Ideally I would want both the id of the row and the employee name so I don't think I can use GROUP_CONCAT to collect more than one column.  There is also no guarantee that there will always be an entry for each client in the employee table so it would need to return an empty/null result for those clients.

I have tried two ways to get this so far in php, both are pretty inefficient in one way or another.

(A) The first was to effectively make a new database connection half way through the first one to return the list of employees associated with that client id but obviously that results in a significant number of database connections being made for just one query.

(B) The second was to pull the entire employee table into an array at the beginning of the code and search through that array to pull out the rows relating to that client id which then have the employee name and row id in.  Over time this is going to end up with a pretty large array being dumped into php instantly.

Is there some way of pulling this out using just a single SQL query?  I'm not all that fussed how the data would come out as I am sure I could sort through it in the php at the other end, but perhaps something along the lines of

Results

```
id |  other data | employees
1  |  data 1     | 1,Fred;2,Jim
2  |  data 2     | 
3  |  data 3     | 3,Peter
4  |  data 4     | 4,Fred;5,Peter;6,James
```

If this has been asked before somewhere I apologise, but I have been searching around a bit over the last week and haven't found all that much to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e.*, c.other_data FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Client c ON e.client_id = c.id
```

So, what you end up with is all the information from both tables grabbed in one query. So, the data would be:

```
     id        client_id    Employee    other_data
     1             1          Fred        data 1
     2             1          Jim         data 1
     3             3          Peter       data 3
     4             4          Fred        data 4
     5             4          Peter       data 4
     6             4          James       data 4
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't return the null row for the client_id = 2 row.

Comment: That's because none of the listed employees use client #2 :). If you want to know something about a specific client, just add a WHERE clauses. Like adding: WHERE e.client_id =2 will give you the employee listing for exclusively client #2.

Comment: @bms, Yes you are right. This is the right answer since the OP accepted it. Sorry for that.

Comment: So without using another query, would I have to compare this list against the full client list to see which of them have no employees assigned to them?